# Incorrect range height error in Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube-data-api

Totally new to JS. The code looks at the YouTube ID "A2" and provides the title of the video and the total views. This works for one ID listed in "A2" but I cannot get it to work with a range.

I have tried to adjust the ranges and used the row and column format.

For example extending the cells to row 7 as you see below gives me this error "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 6 (line 7, file "Code")"

```
function getVideoInfo() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var vid = sheet.getRange("A2:A7").getValue();
  var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet, statistics', {id: vid});
  var item = data.items[0];
  var info = [item.snippet.title, item.statistics.viewCount];
  sheet.getRange("B2:C7").setValues([info]);
}
```

I also tried adjusting the data items to a number other than [0]

Answer (score 0):

- You want to retrieve the values of `snippet.title` and `statistics.viewCount` from IDs put in "A2:A7", and put the result to "B2:C7".
- When the script is used as `var vid = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()` and `sheet.getRange("B2:C2").setValues([info])`, it works fine.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `sheet.getRange("A2:A7").getValue()` retrieves only a value of "A2".
- In the current script, when `sheet.getRange("B2:C7").setValues([info])` is run, it tries to put a value of 1 row and 2 columns to the cells of 6 rows and 2 columns. By this, such error occurs.

It is required to retrieve the values from cells "A2:A7", and put the values of 6 rows and 2 columns to "B2:C7".

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

```
function getVideoInfo() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var vid = sheet.getRange("A2:A7").getValues();
  var info = vid.map(function(e) {
    var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet, statistics', {id: e});
    var item = data.items[0];
    return [item.snippet.title, item.statistics.viewCount];
  });
  sheet.getRange("B2:C7").setValues(info);
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit1:

> If I alter the script to look at all cells in the range A:A, and do not have a value in a cell in range A:A I get the following error. `TypeError: Cannot read property "snippet" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")`. I would like to be able to have the ability to have cells in range A:A blank and still have the script run.

About [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582077/incorrect-range-height-error-in-google-sheets-script/54584412?noredirect=1#comment95999667_54584412), when there are the empty cells in the column "A", you want to put the empty values to the column "B" and "C". I understood like this. By this, I modified my script.

#### Modified script:

```
function getVideoInfo() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var vid = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues(); // Modified
  var info = vid.map(function(e) {
    if (e) { // Added
      var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet, statistics', {id: e});
      var item = data.items[0];
      return [item.snippet.title, item.statistics.viewCount];
    }
    return ["",""]; // Added
  });
  sheet.getRange("B:C").setValues(info); // Modified
}
```

### Edit2:

> I am getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property "snippet" from undefined. (line 8, file "Code")` when there are IDs in `A2:A7` but not an ID in `A8`

From `do not have a value in a cell in range A:A I get the following error.`, I had understood that there are several empty cells in the column "A". But from your comment, it is considered that the issue is the value of the cell. So when an error occurs at `var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet, statistics', {id: e})`, I modified the script to ignore the error.

#### Modified script:

```
function getVideoInfo() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var vid = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues(); // Modified
  var info = vid.map(function(e) {
    if (e) {
      try { // Added
        var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet, statistics', {id: e});
        var item = data.items[0];
        return [item.snippet.title, item.statistics.viewCount];
      } catch(er) { // Added
        return ["",""];
      }
    }
    return ["",""];
  });
  sheet.getRange("B:C").setValues(info); // Modified
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked! Is there a way to make is so that it looks at a larger range without giving an error if there is nothing in "A" to look up off? For example A2:A50 and B2:C50?

Comment: @Bryan Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. But I cannot understand about your new question. What is ``A2:A50 and B2:C50``?

Comment: Apologies. If I alter the script to look at all cells in the range `A:A`, and do not have a value in a cell in range `A:A` I get the following error. `TypeError: Cannot read property "snippet" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")`. I would like to be able to have the ability to have cells in range `A:A` blank and still have the script run.

Comment: @Bryan About your new question, I added the script which modified my script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I am getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property "snippet" from undefined. (line 8, file "Code")`when there are IDs in `A2:A7` but not an ID in `A8`

Comment: @Bryan About your new situation, I added the script which modified my script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: The script runs without an error but now does not populate `B:C` with title or video views. No data is written in the Google Sheet.

Comment: @Bryan I'm sorry. I cannot understand about your new question. Because I have not enough information. So can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to think of about your new question.

Comment: `title` and `viewCount` are not being returned.

Comment: @Bryan For your new question, I modified the script for ignoring the empty cell and the cell which an error occurs at ``var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet, statistics', {id: e})``. About your new situation, I have no information. So can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to think of about your new question. When you provide a sample spreadsheet, please add the situation before and after the script is run. By this, it will help think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad.

Comment: @Bryan By the way, if an error occurs at ``var data = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet, statistics', {id: e})``, ``title`` and ``viewCount`` are not retrieved. So the row is empty. This is due to your new situation about ``TypeError: Cannot read property "snippet" from undefined. (line 7, file "Code")``. Can I ask you about this situation?

Comment: @Bryan And your current situation is largely different from your initial question. So please update your question. By this, other users can also see your current situations.

Comment: @Bryan What is the issue? I cannot understand about it.

Comment: `title` and `viewCount` are not retrieved. The script runs with no errors but does nothing.

Comment: @Bryan In that case, I think that you used the script of "Edit 2". For the spreadsheet, when you used my initial modified script, how was the situation?

Comment: I have exceeded my quota for the API and unable to run the script. I will try tomorrow when I am able. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Bryan It was found that your current question was resolved. But it seems that your additional new question is not resolved. In order to resolve your additional new question, can you provide more information? If you can cooperate to resolve your additional new question, I'm glad.

Comment: I ran Edit 2 (Modified Script) this morning and it worked. I tried to run it again now and it does not update the new `title` and `viewCount` for the new `Id` I added.

Comment: @Bryan I cannot understand about your current situation. Because your issue is changed several times from your initial question. So please provide a sample spreadsheet for replicating your current situation. By this, I would like to correctly understand about your current issue and think of your new issue. I would like to resolve your issue. So if you can cooperate to resolve your additional new question, I'm glad.

Comment: @Bryan If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, please add the detail information of your new issue to your question, because your initial question was resolved as you said. By this, other users including me can also see and cooperate to resolve your new issue.